# how to pass Amazon API Authorisation details from ajax call to invoke lambda function

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

My case:

1. i am using CloudFormation to provisioning aws resources (serverless static web-application).
2. i create amazon api gateway and **IAM** user from CloudFormation template only ( this contains permissions to invoke api gateway only)
3. i am using AuthorizationType: AWS_IAM  in  api gate method.

```
      IamUser:
        Type: 'AWS::IAM::User'
        Properties:
          Policies:
            - PolicyName: api-invoke-policy
              PolicyDocument:
                Version: '2012-10-17'
                Statement:
                  - Effect: Allow
                    Action:
                      - 'execute-api:Invoke'
                      - 'execute-api:ManageConnections'
                    Resource:
                      - 'arn:aws:execute-api:*:account-id:*'
```

5. to invoke that api method we have to pass access key and password
6. i want use this api url to invoke lambda function  from ajax section ( in front-end part)

**example:**

```
    alert("subjet area going to add to db");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/*******',
            type: 'GET',
            data:{subjectAreaId: "$('#subjectAreaId').val()"
                },

            dataType:'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            crossDomain: true,
            success:function(response){
                alert("you are able to invoke lambda function using api url");
                },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                alert("error ");
            }
            })
```

**My question**

**- how to pass this access-key and password ( which are going to get from iam user console ) from ajax call to invoke lambda .**

tried:  i able to invoke that url from postman application (where i entered these key and password in authorisation section)

any suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating an IAM user and sharing the details publically I would suggest using the following:

If you're doing all interactions via a static site then you should take a look at using Cognito User Pools, which provide serverless user authentication/authorization functionality to your application.

Each user could have their own cognito user, or you could use the unauthenticated user. Each of these would have short term credentials generated for them, you can read more about this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/resource-permissions.html).

You can add a [Cognito authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html) to your API Gateway which will only allow access from logged in cognito users, or take the temporary credentials and interact using the [JaveScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/).